# 404 Not found error in deploying a Rails app with Apache2 and Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, apache2, passenger

probably a matter of simple adjustment but I have no idea whats going wrong.

I want a host to be a server for my rails application, which was deployed using Capistrano 3.2.1.
This is a Unix machine running Apache/2.2.15, named eng-perf (corporate internal machine, so no www.address.com syntax at the moment).

I followed [this guide](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_deploying_a_ruby_on_rails_1_x_or_2_x_but_not_rails_gt_3_x_application) and the entire installation process went without any trouble.
I edited the configuration file so that it looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName eng-perf
  # !!! Be sure to point DocumentRoot to 'public'!
  DocumentRoot /var/www/eng_performance/current/public/
  <Directory /var/www/eng-performance/current/public/>
     # This relaxes Apache security settings.
     AllowOverride all
     # MultiViews must be turned off.
     Options -MultiViews
     # Uncomment this if you're on Apache >= 2.4:
     #Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

That gave me this error:

Not Found

The requested URL / was not found on this server.

Next, I tried following the guide by creating the dummies application- [as explained here](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_tutorial_example_writing_and_deploying_a_hello_world_rack_application), and changed the configuration file to be:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName eng-perf
  # !!! Be sure to point DocumentRoot to 'public'!
  DocumentRoot /var/www/rack_example/public/
  <Directory /var/www/rack_exmaple/public/>
     # This relaxes Apache security settings.
     AllowOverride all
     # MultiViews must be turned off.
     Options -MultiViews
     # Uncomment this if you're on Apache >= 2.4:
     #Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

That resulted the exact same Not Found error. So, I guess I'm missing something quite simple..

Also, I tried to restart the apache server and prompted:   `httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using the.machine.ip.addr for ServerName`
As a result I changed the   `ServerName` field to be this address- but that didn't work either.

**Update:**

Following Rich's advise, I updated the configuration file so now I get this output:

```
config.ru:2: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting =>
... [200, { "Content-Type => "text/html" }, ["hello <b>world</b...
...                               ^
config.ru:2: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
... { "Content-Type => "text/html" }, ["hello <b>world</b>"]]
...                               ^
config.ru:2: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end
...-Type => "text/html" }, ["hello <b>world</b>"]]
...                               ^
config.ru:2: unterminated regexp meets end of file
config.ru:2: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
 )}.to_app
          ^ (SyntaxError)
  /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/passenger-4.0.50/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:112:in `eval'
  /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/passenger-4.0.50/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:112:in `preload_app'
  /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/passenger-4.0.50/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:158:in `<module:App>'
  /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/passenger-4.0.50/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/passenger-4.0.50/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use the following:

```
#etc/apache2/apache2.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName eng-perf.com

   DocumentRoot /var/www/rack_example/plublic
   <Directory /var/www/rack_example/public>
      Allow from all
      Options -MultiViews
   </Directory>

   ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin
   <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
       AllowOverride None
       Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I suspect the problem lies with your not calling your domain correctly. It's going to get confused about what it's looking for on the request

Comment: ,Thanks! This has made some progress (I'd really appreciate an explanation on this). 
I get now some other errors- please see the edited question.
thanks!

Comment: You've still not changed yuor ServerName - what's your domain?

Comment: I'm sorry, this is probably some space/indentation error.
I copy-paste the example code and it worked.