# Rails application isn't restarting after system reboot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ruby-on-rails-4, apache2, passenger

I have a Rails 4 application deployed with Apache and Passenger.

The configuration was provided by [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25567772/3001256) and everything worked perfectly.

I created a whenever job that runs when the machine restarts, and I rebooted the machine to check if it works, and it does.

**BUT**, from some reason my web address is no longer reachable. It seems like the machine doesn't route the requests to the application (I get "this webpage isn't available" message from the browser).

I've double checked the    `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` file to make sure the configuration still exists and it does.
I also tried to push again the application to the machine using    `cap production deploy`, and didn't get any errors while doing that.

My configuration in the    `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` file is the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName csi-eng-perf.com
      # !!! Be sure to point DocumentRoot to 'public'!
      DocumentRoot /var/www/eng_performance/current/public/    
      <Directory /var/www/eng_performance/current/public/>
         # This relaxes Apache security settings.
         AllowOverride all
         # MultiViews must be turned off.
         Options -MultiViews
         # Uncomment this if you're on Apache >= 2.4:
         #Require all granted
      </Directory>

      ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin
      <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
         AllowOverride None
         Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
         Order allow,deny
         Allow from all
      </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
```

I have no idea what have gone wrong.

Comment: When your app is unreachable, is Apache running? Can you access other stuff like a static HTML page that is not a part of your Rails app?

Comment: Thanks for this reply!
Can you suggest how to check for all of these issues that you've mentioned?

Comment: @Substantial - anything?

Comment: Apache config is not my area of expertise. The browser message suggests your request timed out, which suggests the server is not running. Depending on your environment, `apachectl status` should tell you what Apache is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as it turns out @Substantial suggestion was correct.

I wasn't able to issue the    `apachectl status` command (needed the installation of another package called    `links`) but the restart command did the trick-     `apachectl -k restart`.